# Microservices, Docker and Node.js debugger

Tags: docker, webstorm, microservices

I have many microservices running in Docker and I can connect to them no problem.

For example:

```
  dashboard-server:
    command: node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9230 src/service/endpoint/dashboard/dashboard-server/dashboard.server.js
    ports:
      - 9230:9230

  userSrv:
    command: node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9231 src/service/user/user-service/user.service.js
    ports:
    - 9231:9231
```

My problem is that I have to connect for each service on different port with different debugger. Is there an option for one debugger to connect to all of the breakpoints?

I am using WebStorm as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your containers runs »his own« node process and populates the debug information on two different ports. One debugger can connect to a single Node Process, so no, you cannot debug both node instances in one debugger instance.